# problems while using array.map for null entry in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-leaflet

I am trying to map the location array but I am unable to do so. I've tried so many stuff in order to map the null object in the array but failed. what mistake am I doing here? if I use a for loop instead of map function then i can do it but i am stuck with the map thing.
...

```
import React from "react";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "./styles.css";
import Icon from "../src/icon.png";
import shadow from "../src/shadow.png";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      location: [
        {
          id: 1,
          machine: 1,
          lat: 51.503,
          lng: -0.091
        },

        null
      ],
      center: [51.505, -0.091],
      zoom: 11,
      marker: null
    };
    this.clickAction = this.clickAction.bind(this);
  }

  Icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: Icon,
    shadowUrl: shadow,
    iconSize: [38, 50],
    shadowSize: [50, 64],
    iconAnchor: [22, 34], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
  });

  openPopUp(marker, id) {
    if (marker && marker.leafletElement) {
      marker.leafletElement.openPopup(id);
    }
  }

  clickAction(id, lat, lng) {
    this.setState({ marker: id, zoom: 16, center: [lat, lng] });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {this.state.location &&
            this.state.location.map(location => {
              return location !== null ? (
                <Marker
                  position={[location?.lat, location?.lng]}
                  icon={this.Icon}
                  ref={this.openPopUp(location?.id)}
                >
                  <Popup> {location?.id} </Popup>
                </Marker>
              ) : null;
            })}
        </Map>

        {
          <List style={{ width: "20%", float: "left" }}>
            {this.state.location &&
              this.state.location.map(({ id, machine, lat, lng }) => {
                return (
                  <ListItem
                    key={id}
                    button
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.clickAction(id, lat, lng);
                    }}
                  >
                    Id {id} <br />
                    machine {machine}
                  </ListItem>
                );
              })}
          </List>
        }
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

...
sample code https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-star-m42qe?file=/src/App.js:0-2858

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `null` in array, hence the error :

```
this.state = {
  location: [
    {
      id: 1,
      machine: 1,
      lat: 51.503,
      lng: -0.091
    },
    null // <---- Remove this
  ],
```

---

If you want to keep `null`, then change this line

```
this.state.location.map(({ id, machine, lat, lng }) => {
```

to, filter out all null entries before mapping it :

```
this.state.location.filter(l => l).map(({ id, machine, lat, lng }) => {
```

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit #SO-filter-null-map]

Comment: i've different objects within an array. so this object is null

Comment: in the real application, an object can have null entries or the object can be null as a whole, it is for this scenario

Comment: thanks, this is working though I also tried something similar in my application but it was giving error. I will try this to my main application

Comment: @deathstranding, you can check the demo, you cal filter all the entries which are blank or null or which is not location, this way you will not get errors.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your second map statement where you destructure the location object inside the map, which will result in error for `null` objects. 
To fix this, you can filter out the null and other falsy locations before mapping them:

```
 this.state.location.filter(location => location).map(/* ... */)
```

You can also use a `Boolean` shorthand to achieve that:

```
this.state.location.filter(Boolean).map(/* ... */)
```